# How to enable buffering of video in the html <video> attribute?

Tags: html, video, video-streaming, html5-video

When I'm watching video embedded in the attribute like in the example below:

```
<video
allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
id="my-video"
class=""
muted
controls
preload="auto">
<source src="@Model.Video.SourceLink" type="video/mp4" /></video>
```

The buffer size of the video contains maximum 30 seconds. There is no possibility of scrolling forward for example from 0:00 to 1:37. After watching a few seconds, the next 30 seconds in loaded to the buffer. Is there any chance to enable preloading all the video to the buffer?

Comment: if you are using an MP4, you will want to make sure the MOOV atom is at the start of the file (so it has access to metadata quickly, that is needed for seeking), and that your server supports byte range requests (so it can quickly jump to the requested chunk). For longer videos you might want to look at HLS/Dash as more flexible solutions

Comment: @Hawos. You have to find a way to read the file's bytes into a buffer (array) as a **blob** and when download is complete, then you can send the blob to the video player. Try something then update your question or ask a new one if still stuck.